# How to reset line counter in per GroupHeaderBand Stimulsoft report?

Tags: report, grouping, row-number, stimulsoft

I'm working on a report that I need to put row number in records but it must be reset on each `GroupHeaderBand`.
I've checked Demo designer, but in those report has been used nested `Business Objects`. I should say I have just one Business Object which has been grouped by one column.
I put `{Line Through}` but it doesnt reset per `GroupHeaderBand`.
Is there anyone who wants help me??

Answer (score 2):

You should use the {Line} system variable. It will reset the numbering for each group.

Answer (score 0):

Use GroupLine in System Variables